# use authentication in a AppServiceProvider in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel
so every logged in user can has a cart so I want to access their cart in my master blade because it's on the header and show all cart products in every pages

so I use this in AppServiceProvider but I need to check if the user logged in it will show cart

```
    public function boot()
    {

        view()->composer('app.shop.2.layouts.master', function($view) {

          $data = \Auth::user()->cart()->get()->first()->products();
          $view->with('data', $data);
        });
    }
```

so everything is ok until the user is logged in but when the user is not logged in it gives me this error :

> Call to a member function cart() on null (View: F:\larav-pay\payment\resources\views\app\shop\2\index.blade.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Auth::check()` to check whether the user is authenticated or not like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('app.shop.2.layouts.master', function($view) {
        if (Auth::check()){
            $data = \Auth::user()->cart()->get()->first()->products();
            $view->with('data', $data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: is it the best way? because I think we must not use auth in appServiceProvider

Comment: Service Provider is the place where the app instance is available which contains bindings, event listeners, middleware and even routes. So we can also use Auth in AppServiceProvider.